# Execute func in PHP depends on what's sent by Angular

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

met another challenge inspecting web development, will be grateful if anyone can help. So... I've got a few buttons each have to execute some func, like that `ng-click='loadA', ng-click='loadB'` etc. I'm making request like

```
$scope.loadA = function() {
  $http({
      method:  'POST',
      url:     'generate.php',
      data:    {keyword : 'A'},
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  })
  .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
  })
};
```

On the backend I've got

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$a = $request->keyword;
echo $a;
```

And even that simplified code return just empty object. Can't get what's wrong. Finally I want to receive on the serverside some 'keyword' and depends on that execute some func. In jQuery and PHP I've done it like

```
switch ($_POST['keyword']) {
  case 'A':
    get_A();
    break;
  case 'B':
    get_B();
    break;
};
```

But I'm stuck trying to perform it in Angular + PHP... So... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one.

```
$request = json_decode($postdata,true);
$a = $request["keyword"];
```

Comment: Funny, but it works. Thx, man, didn't know about that difference.